# How do I use cURL to perform multiple simultaneous requests?

Tags: curl, request

I'd like to use **cURL** to test flood handling on my server. Right now I'm using this on a Windows command line:

```
curl www.example.com
```

which will `GET` the page once. I'd like to now do the same thing, except instead of one request, I want to generate at least 10 requests at once. How would I do this?

Comment: curl www.example.com#[0-10] might come close.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

While curl is a very useful and flexible tool, isn't intended for this type of use. There are other tools available which will let you make multiple concurrent requests to the same URL.

[ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is a very simple yet effective tool of this type, which works for any web server (despite the introduction focusing on Apache server).

[Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) is a more sophisticated tool, which can let you specify many different URLs to use in a load test. This lets you mix requests for cheap and expensive pages, which may more closely resemble standard load for your website.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. In the end though, I created a batch script that executes the curl I need, and then another batch script to execute that batch script multiple times using `start cmd /c curl.bat` multiple times.

Comment: ab in itself is a good tool to have in your toolkit.

Answer (score 30):

Starting from `7.68.0` curl can fetch several urls in parallel. This example will fetch urls from `urls.txt` file with 3 parallel connections:

```
curl --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 3 --config urls.txt
```

urls.txt:

```
url = "example1.com"
url = "example2.com"
url = "example3.com"
url = "example4.com"
url = "example5.com"
```

Comment: For those who want to check concurrent connection for POST method, the following example works:


curl --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 8 -X POST -d "mama=mia" --config urls.txt

Comment: is there a way to provide different body to same url in parallel request.

Answer (score 7):

Curl may not do it itself but bash can.

```
curl -o 1.txt -X GET https://foo & curl -o 2.txt -X GET https://foo
```

Comment: This won't make the requests concurrent, this is the equivalent of running curl in loop.

Comment: Yes they are concurrent: The `&` connector puts the first command in the "background" and immediately launches the second one. It doesn't scale very well to flood testing, though.

Comment: I tried it, it's not concurrent. This is more like a loop as @Jonathan mentioned

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to use GNU Parallel with Curl.

Here is a simplified example that does 100 curl requests total, 10 at a time (concurrently):

```
seq 100 | parallel --max-args 0 --jobs 10 "curl https://www.example.com"
```

`seq 100` generates a list of numbers that we pipe into `parallel`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
... and so on
```

Then we use the `--max-args 0` option which means that it will execute 1 job per argument. Don't change this number. Identically alias option is `-n`.

Docs say:

> -n 0 means read one argument, but insert 0 arguments on the command line.

Then we use the `--jobs 10` option which will run up to 10 jobs in parallel/concurrently. Identically alias options are `-j`, `--procs`/`-P`.

Docs say:

> Number of jobslots on each machine. Run up to N jobs in parallel.  0 means as many as possible. Default is 100% which will run one job per CPU core on each machine.

Below is a more functional example which prints the return code, hides the output and depending on if the command succeeded (`&&`) or not (`||`) print a SUCCESS or FAIL message along with it, which I find useful for my debugging purposes:

```
seq 100 | parallel --max-args 0 --jobs 10 "curl -w '%{http_code}\n' https://www.example.com --output /dev/null --location --silent && printf SUCCESS\n\n || printf FAIL\n\n"
```

[image: example output of using GNU Parallel to Curl]

Comment: This method will be slower since it can't reuse connections.

Comment: This answer on native curl parallel requests seems like it should be the accepted answer > https://stackoverflow.com/a/66998509/292408

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case and I ended up writing a python script:

```
import threading
import requests

def thread_function(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=('http://foo',))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=('http://bar',))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do curl  -I -k "https://www.example.com"; done
```

This is the script that work for me. Change the value of 10 in case you need to add more request.

Answer (score 0):

As of version `7.66.0` you can do the following using `-Z, --parallel`:

```
curl -Z https://example.com -o file1 https://example.com -o file2
```