# Passing key value from json in CURL request (command line)

Tags: json, windows, curl, command-line

I am using a REST API to move a user into a group, but need to append the group name to the URL when I run the command.

So the path to my REST API is:

```
http://server:8080/rest/api/2/group/user?groupname
```

And it's expecting "groupname" to be passed as "groupname="Name%20Of%20Group"

i.e.

```
http://server:8080/rest/api/2/group/user?groupname="Name%20Of%20Group"
```

The full command I'm running on Windows is

```
curl -u name:pass -X POST --data @add_user.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://server:8080/rest/api/2/group/user?groupname
```

add_user.txt is structured like this

```
{
    "name": "tim",
    "groupname": "MY%20TEST%20GROUP"
},
{
    "name": "carol",
    "groupname": "MY%20TEST%20GROUP"
}
```

It's looping through the names I believe, but I want CURL to pick up on each "groupname" defined in the file.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. each curl call makes a single request.
2. looks like you need to change from POST to GET and use the -G, --get option to add the values as parameters after the ?

See [How do I use cURL to perform multiple simultaneous requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624967/how-do-i-use-curl-to-perform-multiple-simultaneous-requests)

HTH